# Slow video frame by frame reading OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, frame-rate

I am trying to do some simple contour detection through each of the frames of a 1080P, 120FPS video (about 30k frames in total).

However, `openCV's VideoCapture` takes a very long time to read each frame from the video (maybe 15 frames per second. but this takes way too long for to get through 30k frames, takes frame from video and turns it into Mat, where then I can do some CV on it).

A snippet of my reading code looks like this:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> findPostiveFrames(Rect roi){
    ArrayList<Integer> postiveFrames = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    currentVC.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1000);
    currentVC.set(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1000);
    Mat mat = new Mat(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < currentVC.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); i++){
        currentVC.read(mat);
        Mat submat = mat.submat(roi);
        System.out.println("i: " + i);

    }
    System.out.println("donezo");
    return postiveFrames;
}
```

Comment: what are `currentVC.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1000);
    currentVC.set(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1000);` for in your code? Why don't you precompute `Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` only once before the loop? What hardware are you using to run the applicatio?

Comment: a 2012 MacBookPro. i5. 16gb RAM. I was messing with those two paramters to see if it affected anything; it didn't. I took out the .read(mat) and the speed improved by many magnitudes, so I am quite certain it's the .read(mat) that is the culprit.

Comment: how's the video encoded? Is it on your local drive? Can you watch the video with VLC in realtime? Did you try different video files?

Comment: It's a 1080P MPEG4 file encoded by H.264. VLC can't play it in real time. I have tried a smaller file (H.264, about 720P) and it was perhaps 1.7 times to 2 times the speed in terms of reading through the frames.

Comment: is the 15 fps you reach in openCV similar to the VLC speed or does it differ much (e.g. 30-60 fps in VLC?). Unfortunately, image decoding isn't that cheap (although much cheaper than encoding).

Comment: I wasn't able to find out about the playback FPS in VLC, but it's so laggy and buggy that it's pretty much unwatchable.I would think we are in the single digits in terms of FPS in VLC.